# How to create a trigger in mysql from GO. Using DELIMITER seems not supported

Tags: mysql, go

Creating tables from GO is not a problem. all standard driver support.
I'm trying to create a trigger, but that seems not easy....
I tried 
`res, err := db.DBcon.Exec("DELIMITER $$")` 
but that fails

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Fails how? What error do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

ah creep... that's only mysql-cli and Workbench specific...
I don't have to use the delimiter. I can just create the trigger using

```golang
db.DBcon.Exec(`
    CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER <TRIGGER_NAME> 
        AFTER INSERT ON <TABLE_NAME> FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            <Do some statement>;
        END;
`)
```